Docker using wrong runc version
maybe someone could help me with a strange issue I have appearing suddenly after a full system update: building a Dockerfile with docker build works flawlessly, but using docker-compose build with the same (very simple) Dockerfile throws an error on the very first RUN command in the Dockerfile
Incorrect Usage: flag provided but not defined: -keep
NAME:
    runc run - create and run a container

USAGE:
    runc run [command options] <container-id>

I have to machines running arch linux, I updated one from docker v25 to v26, the other is still on v25. On the machine with the older version (which in other ways also might be slightly different), the same compose script works fine.
As far as I understand, the docker on the updated machine is somehow using the wrong runc version after the update, which doesn't support -keep.
docker version reports
 Version:           26.1.4
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.22.3
 Git commit:        5650f9b102
 Built:             Thu Jun  6 18:42:55 2024
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.4
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.22.3
  Git commit:       de5c9cf0b9
  Built:            Thu Jun  6 18:42:55 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.7.18
  GitCommit:        ae71819c4f5e67bb4d5ae76a6b735f29cc25774e.m
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.2
  GitCommit:        v1.0.2-0-g52b36a2d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

where the runc version does not match the version reported by runc --version which says
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.21.6
libseccomp: 2.5.5

I have even tried to run runc run -keep which doesn't give the error flag provided but not defined, but when runnin runc run -blabla it does. Hence, by the globally installed runc, -keep seems to be recognized as a valid flag.
I have also tried to install docker and docker-compose in a fresh arch virtual machine, where it works flawlessly. Hence, the arch package itself seems not to be broken, only my install.
My idea was maybe to manually override the container runtime with /sbin/runc which seems to have the flag, or somehow find out which runc docker is using.
As an info, the arch package versions are:
docker 1:26.1.4-1
docker-compose 2.27.1-1

